# How to resize Moviepy to fullscreen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, moviepy

I am making a game using pygame and I wanted to add cut scenes to it. The pygame movie module however doesn’t work anymore so I had to resort to using moviepy. Moviepy isn’t that well documented from what I can see so I’m having some trouble figuring it out. I got it to work using this block of code but all I need now is to full screen it (desired window screen is 640x400). So how would I go about doing so? Thank you in advance.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from pygame import *# Window display
WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 400
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = FULLSCREEN

#display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)  #define screen values
display.set_caption("I'm Working!")
Credits = 'Untitled.mp4'
def playVid(video):
    clip = VideoFileClip(video)
    clip.resize(DISPLAY).preview()
    return


playVid(Credits)
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190332/moviepy-fullscreen) might help you.

Comment: @Jerrybibo it’s a class project, it needs to work on multiple machines so editing the library isn’t practical.

Comment: @Moe. I’m a collaborator on moviepy, so if you can find an edit to the library that works for you, I can get it merged in as an option :)

Comment: @tburrows13 
I did what the linked question did and changed in Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io preview.py line 94

`screen = pg.display.set_mode(clip.size)` 
to

`screen = pg.display.set_mode(clip.size,pg.FULLSCREEN)`
 and it worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, this looks like a super simple feature to add. When do you need it done by? I'll just make another parameter for `clip.preview` which, when set, calls `pg.display.setmode` with the full screen option.

Comment: @tburrows13 that’s perfect thank you so much, my assignment is due on Monday so if it’s possible to do that by then that would be great!

Comment: Ok, that should be doable. Have you used Github before? Don’t worry if not.

Comment: Would you mind checking out be feature [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/773)? If it works for you, I’ll merge it.

Comment: @tburrows13 I mentioned all the comments I had at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964841/moviepy-plays-videos-out-of-sync

Comment: @Moe, I've saw the question that you've now deleted, and I've update the pull request so that it should hopefully work now. As soon as you let me know that it works, I can merge it.

Comment: @tburrows13 works perfectly, please merge it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Ok, would you like it pushed to PyPI as well so that you can pip install it?

Comment: @tburrows13 I install my modules through pycharm, I think it updates automatically.

Comment: @Moe it will be getting them from the PyPI servers then :) I'll push a PyPI update now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of moviepy version 0.2.3.4, you can call `clip.preview(fullscreen=True)` to make your preview fullscreen. Press `Esc` or the quit button to quit. See the [pull request](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/773) for further info.

Run `pip install moviepy --upgrade` to update moviepy to the latest version.

Comment: I was also wondering if you could edit the 67th line. fps=15. Change it to just fps so we can input the video fps manually for each video?

Comment: You can specify the fps with `clip.preview(fps=30, fullscreen=True)`. The `fps=15` is just a default value, for if you don't pass `fps` as an argument.